# ImportError: "Module not found error after npm link"

Tags: npm, module, hyperlink, rollup

I've installed a package App1 into App2 using npm link 'App1'. I can see the package in the node_modules in App2. But when I try to run the app, I'm getting below error..

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'App1' in App2/src

thanks in advance